# Flutter Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)'

Tags: flutter, dart

Using flutter's plugin **file_picker**, runs smoothly till when you select a file, whenever i select a file, the entire app crashes, line in *pubspec.yaml* `file_picker: ^1.12.0` and flutter code is:

```
onTap: () async {
  File file = await FilePicker.getFilePath(type: FileType.video);
},
```

This has been eating me alive and none of the solutions i found online have helped. The stacktrace is:

```
D/FilePickerDelegate(16658): Selected type video/*
D/EGL_emulation(16658): eglMakeCurrent: 0x9f7462a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x8fc0a3d0)
D/FlutterView(16658): Detaching from a FlutterEngine: io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@c94b1b9
I/FilePickerDelegate(16658): [SingleFilePick] File URI:content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/40
E/FilePickerUtils(16658): Getting for API 19 or abovecontent://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/40
E/AndroidRuntime(16658): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-4
E/AndroidRuntime(16658): Process: com.lulliezy.video, PID: 16658
E/AndroidRuntime(16658): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
E/AndroidRuntime(16658):    at com.mr.flutter.plugin.filepicker.FilePickerDelegate$2.run(FilePickerDelegate.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(16658):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
E/FilePickerUtils(16658): Document URI
E/FilePickerUtils(16658): Downloads External Document URI
D/FlutterView(16658): Attaching to a FlutterEngine: io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@c94b1b9
I/FilePickerDelegate(16658): Absolute file path:/storage/emulated/0/Download/videoplayback.mp4
D/EGL_emulation(16658): eglCreateContext: 0xa3f05780: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation(16658): eglMakeCurrent: 0xa3f05780: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa3f03200)
D/EGL_emulation(16658): eglMakeCurrent: 0x9f7462a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x8fc0a3d0)
D/EGL_emulation(16658): eglMakeCurrent: 0xa3f05780: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa3f03200)
E/Surface (16658): queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -19
E/EGL_emulation(16658): tid 16675: swapBuffers(547): error 0x300d (EGL_BAD_SURFACE)
D/EGL_emulation(16658): eglMakeCurrent: 0x9f7462a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x8fc0a3d0)
D/FlutterView(16658): Detaching from a FlutterEngine: io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@c94b1b9
D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(16658): Detaching FlutterEngine from the Activity that owns this Fragment.
D/FlutterEngine(16658): Destroying.
D/FlutterEnginePluginRegistry(16658): Destroying.
```

Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Also, am fairly new to Flutter/Dart, so please excuse my ignorance if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try upgrade your flutter version

You can also take a look at this [thread](https://github.com/miguelpruivo/flutter_file_picker/issues/286)

Answer (score 0):

You have to upgrade the file_picker version. The getFile() is no longer available in the latest version in favor of pickFiles().
Have a look at [this](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker/changelog)